# STM32 - Clock signal generator using a timer - STM32CubeMX generated code

Tags: stm32, clock, timer

I am trying to generate a clock of 1.4 MHz using the STM32F103C8Tx using STM32CubeMX.

First of all, in my code I have pin PB13 as output and in main I toggle it every two seconds. This works.

Now the more important part. Things I have set up in CubeMX:

- I have set up the base clock of the device to 28 MHz.
- TIM3 Channel2: <s>Output compare CH2</s> PWM Generation CH2
- Internal Clock
- Timer3: [image]

I have compiled the generated code in the IDE from OpenSTM32 and uploaded it. The LED is blinking at the set interval, but I have no output on the pin <s>B5</s> A7 (Timer3 channel 2). This is verified on the oscilloscope.

Code(main):

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();

  //These two lines were manually added
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

  while (1)
  {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
        HAL_Delay(5000);
  }
}
```

The rest can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/icamaster/41f2f51cf6a27857e1a3611aaef63649).

Comment: I think output compare of a timer channel does not mean physical output to a pin. It just compares the timer's (output)value to some preset value and generates an interrupt or anything if matches.

Comment: I am now using PWM output in Mode 1.

Comment: In my case, I found that the `HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);` line was not needed (I don't think it hurt either).

Comment: The generated clock signal should be exactly 1.4 MHz or are there  any other value allowed?

Comment: @Bence Kaulics: Yes, you are right. Dividing by 20 instead of 19 is closer (in fact, is exactly 1.4 MHz if the 28 MHz is exact). I have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set a period for the timer in field *"Counter Period (AutoReload Register - 16 bits value)"* (third line). This, together with the prescaler (first line) and the APB1 frequency, determines the timer frequency.

The "Pulse" setting for the PWM outputs determines the *duty cycle*. All PWM outputs for timer 3 have the *same* frequency (the timer frequency), but independent duty cycle settings (one per PWM output).

[image: Screenshot from STM32CubeMx, for the STM32 Nucleo board STM32F042K6, timer 3]

Note that it is easy to make off-by-one errors. This applies both to the prescaler (for example, 0 means divide by 1) and the timer period. For instance, in this example where the APB1 frequency is 48 MHz, the frequency is 48 MHz / 3 / 51 = 313.725 kHz (and not, for example, 48 MHz / 3 / 50 = 320 kHz). For the PWM setting, on the other hand, the setting is the actual effective value (not +1). The duty cycles are 45.1%, 64.7%, 13.7%, and 5.9%, respectively.

(I have a similar setup for a different STM32 processor, but also set up with STM32CubeMX and compiled/run under OpenSTM32. I have verified the frequency and all four duty cycles on an oscilloscope (within the measurement accuracy).)

In your case, presuming the APB1 frequency is actually 28 MHz, a counter period of 19 would give exactly 1.4000000 MHz (28 MHz / 1 / 20) - though if you are using the internal oscillator not more than three significant digits are warranted (I found mine to be off by about 0.37%, within the specification of 1%). If you set the PWM pulse to 10 then the duty cycle should become 50.0%.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem is that currently the output is stuck on "HIGH". I will link you some screenshots of the Cube project, maybe you are able to spot my mistake. http://imgur.com/a/HI9fI
I also added before "while(1)" in main these following lines : HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(&htim2);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used TIM2 this time, on channel 2, which is pin PA1, if it matters.

Comment: I just did a rebuild and now it's working. Thanks  you

Comment: @Cezar Chirila: You should set "Counter Period" (third line), not the prescaler, to 18. The prescaler (first line) should remain on 0.

Comment: @Cezar Chirila: Did it work for "Counter Period" equal to 0, but the prescaler different from zero?

Comment: Yes. It worked for a "Prescaler" equal to 0, and "Counter period" of 18.

Comment: I need to ask, why do I have to modifiy the "Counter period". Isn't 28MHz / 1 / 19 equal to 28MHz / 19 / 1.

Comment: @Cezar Chirila: If you want to vary the duty cycle (in a fine-grained way) then it needs to be "Prescaler" equal to 0, and a "Counter period" of 18. Otherwise only about one PWM duty cycle is possible (50%?) - if it works at all.

Comment: I found something interesting. I am not able to generate the signal on TIM3 or TIM4. Only on TIM2. Everything else is the same, except Clocksource Internal is a checkbox (which I checked). Everything else is the same. I have added the lines :   HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(&htim3);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
    
  HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(&htim4);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

Comment: Nevermind, I had to rebuild it two times, strange. I need to set up my Workbench better, right now I only build it there and I upload the bin via ST-Link Utility.